# Can I merge two Javascript functions that have different unique names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have two Javascript functions, I was wondering if it's possible to merge them somehow, as I believe it is breaking functionality in a third function. The two I'd like two somehow merge are as follows:

```
    $("select[name='YourLocation']").on("change", function () {
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case 'Branch':
                $('.RN, .BN, .DN').hide();
                $('.RN, .BN, .DN').show();
                break;
            case 'Region':
                $('.RN, .BN, .DN').hide();
                $('.RN').show();
                $('.DN').show();
                break;
            case 'Division':
                $('.RN, .BN, .DN').hide();
                $('.DN').show();
                break;
            default:
                $('.RN, .BN, .DN').hide();
        }
    });

    $('.RN, .BN, .DN').hide();

    //2nd function

    $("select[name='ReqType']").on("change", function () {
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case 'SMAC':
                $('.MCN, .CN').hide();
                $('.MCN, .CN').show();
                break;
            case 'CreditCardACHPosting':
                $('.MCN, .CN').hide();
                $('.MCN, .CN').show();
                break;
            case 'Mission Account Research':
                $('.MCN, .CN').hide();
                $('.MCN, .CN').show();
                break;
            case 'Mission AR Credit Memo':
                $('.MCN, .CN').hide();
                $('.MCN, .CN').show();
                break;
            case 'Mission AR Debit Memo':
                $('.MCN, .CN').hide();
                $('.MCN, .CN').show();
                break;
            case 'Customer Refund':
                $('.MCN, .CN').hide();
                $('.MCN, .CN').show();
                break;
            case 'Commercial Inquiry':
                $('.MCN, .CN').hide();
                $('.MCN, .CN').show();
                break;
            default:
                $('.MCN, .CN').hide();
        }
    });
    $('.MCN, .CN').hide();
```

This is the "submit" function that is breaking, which I believe is due to the above.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('DateCreated').value = getDate();
};
function FormRequest() {
    checkFile()
    var formData = form2js('JsonForm', '.', false, "", "", true);
    document.getElementById('txthiddenjson').value = JSON.stringify(formData, null, '\t');
}
```

Code for button:

```
                                    <button class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-lg" name="Submit" onclick="FormRequest();">Submit</button>
                                <input type="hidden" name="txthiddenjson" id="txthiddenjson" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can remove the `break` calls and just let the `case` statements fall through. Also, calling `hide()` then `show()` immediately is pretty pointless. Merging those event handlers looks like it would cause more issues than it solves. You would probably have more success solving your problem if you gave details the of the error you have that's breaking the functionality

Comment: Of course it's possible, but I'm not sure why you're needing to do this. Seems like a case of [the x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Can you provide more information as to what the actual problem is that you are trying to solve, rather than asking about a particular solution?

Comment: Yes indeed - I have two drop downs, named "YourLocation" and "ReqType," based on the choice I am picking from the drop down, I want a hidden field to appear, which is why I'm using the .hide() and .show() based on their CSS name (.RN, .BN, .DN, .MCN, & .CN).

Comment: @Helene Are the groups of hidden fields (.RN, .BN, .DN) and (.MCN, .CN) mutually exlusive? Meaning that only hidden fields from a single group can be showing at a time? Or can you have one or more of the first group and one or more of the second group showing at the same time?

Comment: @mhodges Yes, if I choose "Branch" from the first group of hidden fields, it will show (.BN, .DN, .RN), and if I choose "CreditCardACHPosting" from the 2nd group, it will show me (.MCN, .CN), so what's what I want to occur. When when I "submit" the page using the function I've tied to it, it doesn't submit.

Comment: @Helene Check to see if my solution works for you. I still don't have much context as to exactly what you're trying to do (especially about the form submitting?), but I took my best guess. If you still have issues, please provide more of your code and context as to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to merge the two functions into one, you can simplify it like so:

1) You can start by combining the selector in the event listener binding.

2) Then once inside, you can determine which select is triggering the change event by checking the `name` attribute.

3) Since you have `$(".RN, .BN, .DN").hide()` happening in every case of your switch statement for the `YourLocation` dropdown, we can abstract that out and run it at the beginning, removing the need for the default case, as well as reducing duplicate code. The same concept applies for `$(".MCN, .CN").hide()` for the `ReqType` dropdown. Then in the case statements, all you have to worry about is showing the ones you want to show.

```js
$('.MCN, .CN').hide();
$('.RN, .BN, .DN').hide();

$("select[name='YourLocation'], select[name='ReqType']").on("change", function () {
  var trigger = $(this);
  if (trigger.attr("name") === "YourLocation") {
    $('.RN, .BN, .DN').hide();
  }
  else if (trigger.attr("name") === "ReqType"){
    $('.MCN, .CN').hide();
  }
  
  switch (trigger.val()) {
    case 'Branch': {
      $('.RN, .BN, .DN').show();
      break;
    }
    case 'Region': {
      $('.RN, .DN').show();
      break;
    }
    case 'Division': {
      $('.DN').show();
      break;
    }
    case 'SMAC': {
      $('.MCN, .CN').show();
      break;
    }
    case 'CreditCardACHPosting': {
      $('.MCN, .CN').show();
      break;
    }
    case 'Mission Account Research': {
      $('.MCN, .CN').show();
      break;
    }
    case 'Mission AR Credit Memo': {
      $('.MCN, .CN').show();
      break;
    }
    case 'Mission AR Debit Memo': {
      $('.MCN, .CN').show();
      break;
    }
    case 'Customer Refund': {
      $('.MCN, .CN').show();
      break;
    }
    case 'Commercial Inquiry': {
      $('.MCN, .CN').show();
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="YourLocation">
  <option value="">--Select Location--</option>
  <option value="Branch">Branch</option>
  <option value="Region">Region</option>
  <option value="Division">Division</option>
</select>
<select name="ReqType">
  <option value="">--Select Req Type--</option>
  <option value="SMAC">SMAC</option>
  <option value="CreditCardACHPosting">CreditCardACHPosting</option>
  <option value="Mission Account Research">Mission Account Research</option>
  <option value="Mission AR Credit Memo">Mission AR Credit Memo</option>
  <option value="Mission AR Debit Memo">Mission AR Debit Memo</option>
  <option value="Customer Refund">Customer Refund</option>
  <option value="Commercial Inquiry">Commercial Inquiry</option>
</select>
<div class="hiddenItems">
  <div class="RN">.RN</div>
  <div class="BN">.BN</div>
  <div class="DN">.DN</div>
  <div class="MCN">.MCN</div>
  <div class="CN">.CN</div>
</div>
```

As far as submitting the form goes, `<button>` elements inside a form will submit the form by default. Since you want to do some processing/validation prior to the form being submitted, you will need to call `event.preventDefault()` and then submit the form manually by using `$("form").submit()` like so:

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <!-- Rest of form -->
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-lg" name="Submit">Submit</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="txthiddenjson" id="txthiddenjson" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$("#myForm").on("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit
  checkFile();
  var formData = form2js('JsonForm', '.', false, "", "", true);
  $('#txthiddenjson').val(JSON.stringify(formData, null, '\t'));
  $(this).submit(); // manually submit form when you are ready
});
```

Comment: thank you, I will try this out and see if it's working now. :)

Comment: This code works beautifully in its combined nature, but I am still having an issue with submitting. I've added the code for the submit button above.

Comment: @Helene Added a little explanation of how I simplified everything, if that helps.

Comment: @Helene Ah, okay, you're close. I will update my answer to include the form submit

Comment: @Helene Okay, check my updated answer with the form submit code at the bottom and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and let you know!

Comment: The code works great, but still doesn't allow me to submit if I'm using the previously merged function. Grr. I'll keep digging and see what's up. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Helene Did you remove the `onclick` attribute from your `<button>`?

Comment: I did, yes. I copied your formatting for the submit button above